# Динамический массив в классе

Tags: c++

Существует пример создания динамического двумерного массива:

```
float **Matrix = new float*[SizeOfMatrix];
for(i = 0; i<SizeOfMatrix;i++)
        {
                Matrix[i] = new float[SizeOfMatrix];
        }
```

`SizeOfMatrix` - размер матрицы.
А как объявить класс, чтоб создавать объекты подобные этой матрице?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyType
{
     float **Matrix;
     int Size;
    public:
     MyType(int SizeOfMatrix)
     {
         Size=SizeofMatrix;
         float **Matrix = new float*[SizeOfMatrix];
         for(int i = 0; i<SizeOfMatrix;i++)
        {
                Matrix[i] = new float[SizeOfMatrix];
        }
     }
     ~MyType()
     {
         for(int i = 0; i<Size;i++)
        {
                delete [](Matrix[i]);
        }
        delete [](Matrix);
     }

};
```

UPD: Извините, неправильно написал освобождение памяти. Исправлено.

Comment: Да, правильно.

Comment: Вот только пытаюсь адаптировать к своему коду, обращаться к объекту по индексам... не получается

Comment: `delete []`!!!

Comment: delete**[]**(Matrix[i]); если не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Даниил Перегрузите оператор `operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)`.

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то надо перегрузить оператор [], как-то так:

    float* operator[]( int id ){ return Matrix[id]; }

Comment: как перегрузить оператор (дибильный вопрос, знаю) - но у меня неразбериха получается полная

Answer (score 3):

Каноническая реализация класса матрицы **на современном `C++`:**

```
template <typename Y> struct Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
        : holder_(new Y[width * height]), width_(width), height_(height) { }

    const Y& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const {
        // Можно и 'throw', но подсадит производительность.
        assert(i < width_ && j < height_);
        return *(holder.get() + j * width + i);
    }

    Y& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {
        assert(i < width_ && j < height_);
        return *(holder.get() + j * width + i);
    }

    // Остальные операции.

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Y> holder_;
    std::size_t width_;
    std::size_t height_;
}
```

---

Отмечу также, что для оптимизации сложных вычислений можно использовать их проксирование с помощью `expression templates`, что очень неплохо подчеркивает преимущества шаблонного `C++`. Детали реализации *(и многое другое, разумеется)*, можно подсмотреть у библиотеки [**boost::ublas.**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Comment: Молодец, только человеку это будет пока еще рановато

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить... А почему "современный С++" чем этот код <strike>современнее</strike> лучше чем реализация приведенная выше?<br>
простое <b>всем привычное и понятное ООП</b> уже не в моде?<br><br>
Спрашиваю т.к. если чегото сильно не знаю и(или) не понимаю - хотелось бы это исправить...

Comment: @AlexWindHope Ну хотя бы тем, что в моем случае выделение памяти выполняется в одном месте в конструкторе. А человек, который писал код выше *(из-за использования `raw` указателей)*, например, в первом варианте неправильно освободил память. Ну плюс там мелочи вроде поддержки любого типа данных в матрице и разные `dimension'ы`.

Comment: @AlexWindHope Что вы вкладываете во фразу **"привычное и понятное ООП"** и где, грубо говоря, вы вообще здесь и в ответе выше нашли ООП?

Comment: Т.е. из-за того что кто-то неправильно освободил память то ООП в С+<strike>ацтой</strike> не подходит?<br>И про "современность" вы так и не ответили - мне очень интересно, я не со зла 2ой раз переспрашиваю :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope Из-за того, что кто-то неправильно освободил память, бывает, что 20 человек в проекте на 3 мегабайта кода начинают это самое освобождение искать) А современность здесь заключается в использовании `std::unique_ptr`, который появился в C++0x. *Вообще говоря, лично я являюсь рьяным ценителем библиотеки `boost`, compile-time разворачиваний шаблонов, метапрограммирования и новых стандартов `C++`, поэтому иногда тоже впадаю в крайности.*

Comment: @AlexWindHope А вы мне так и не ответили, что вы вообще вкладываете в значение термина OOП)

Answer (score 0):

Автор привёл не самый эффективный вариант динамического массива, если его конечно интересует эффективность. Привожу класс, подобный ответу выше, только с другим способом выделения памяти и методом доступа:

```
class Matrix
{
    float* data;
    int size;
public:
    Matrix(int matSize)
    {
        size=matSize;
        data=new float[size*size];
    }
    ~Matrix()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
    float* operator[](int row)
    {
        return data+row*size;
    }
};
```

Этот код и короче, и быстрее работает.

Использовать так:

```
Matrix mat(5);
mat[2][4]=3242.542;
mat[3][1]=3.1415;
```